# Random dating system in awarded badges page (and elsewhere?)

Tags: bug, badges, dates

The awarded badges page has a misleading glitch in the listing of the dates awarded.

On Meta.SE, at the time of this post, the point at which it begins adding the year is July 14th, 2013 sometime between 19:13 and 21:18 (10 months and 26 days and some hours ago), as can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20?page=54), and verified [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23?page=77).

Why is it such a random number of time ago and not a round number like 11 months or prior to the current calendar year?

Comment: FWIW, July 15, 2013 was 11×30 = 330 days ago. Maybe the implementation of "11 months ago" uses "1 month = 30 days".

Comment: @senshin that seems incredibly plausible.  Just ends up quirky.

Comment: Related feature request: [Date format consistency: show year and capitalize month on badge pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247943/193139)